# Pandas - Count numbers of logs based in a time frequency

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a comples analysis to perform in pandas, its basic a chalenge.
I need to count qty of logs based in a time frequency in minutes.

i have the dataframe below with logs. And i define that frequency os analyse will be 00:05:00 minutes.

´´´

```
user_id data       time_log_in_hours
user1  24/03/2020  00:01:00
user1  24/03/2020  00:07:00
user1  24/03/2020  00:11:00
user2  24/03/2020  00:25:00
user2  24/03/2020  00:27:00
user2  24/03/2020  00:27:00
user3  25/03/2020  01:36:00
user3  25/03/2020  01:37:00
user3  25/03/2020  01:38:00
```

´´´

The expect result is dataframe below that should count qty of logs by determinated frequency.
i will ever consider time in rage between to times separated for 5 minutes.
All rage in time available in 24 hours need to bi in header separated for define range on 5 minutes in this case.

´´´

```
User   date       00:05:00 00:10:00 00:15:00 00:25:00 00:30:00...01:35:00 01:40:00...
user1  24/03/2020 1        1        1        0        0       ...0        0...
user2  24/03/2020 0        0        0        1        2       ...0        0...
user3  25/03/2020 0        0        0        0        0       ...0        3...
```

´´´

Is possible to build it in pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try

```
s=df.groupby([df['user_id'],df['data'],df['time_log_in_hours'].dt.ceil('5 min')]).size().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
time_log_in_hours user_id        data  ...  0 days 00:30:00  0 days 01:40:00
0                   user1  24/03/2020  ...                0                0
1                   user2  24/03/2020  ...                2                0
2                   user3  25/03/2020  ...                0                3
[3 rows x 8 columns]
```